# iis vulnerability

Tags: iis

If IIS has a vulnerability and a administrator shuts down port 80 so IIS cannot listen on it. Will that same vulnerability be present on port 443(https)? Thank you for taking the time to look consider this.

Comment: I agree with Paul, but quick answer here. It depends, if there's applications that can be exploited that listen on the port.

Comment: The correct answer is: It depends on the vulnerability

Comment: I know this is related to your other question. Is there a business need for you to have port 80 open? Or do you just not want to have to use port 443?

Comment: @Nixphoe, Yes there is a business need. We need to host a site using port 80 the firewall isn't letting the requests through because of its current ruleset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the exact vulnerability, but in general yes. If the vulnerability is with an application on the IIS server, then it is extremely likely to be still vulnerable.